# WPDB Table Does Not Exist

Tags: wpdb

From this code:

```
global $wpdb;
$sidebar_table = $wpdb->prefix . 'w3care_sidebar_position'; 
$checkad = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT ad_id, sidebar_position, ad_type FROM `%s` WHERE page_id = '11646' AND page_type='page'",$sidebar_table ));
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
WordPress database error Table 'wp_rainnews.'wp_w3care_sidebar_position'' doesn't exist for query SELECT ad_id, sidebar_position, ad_type FROM `'wp_w3care_sidebar_position'` WHERE page_id = '11646' AND page_type='page' /* From [siteurl/] in [/urltopluginindex/index.php:855] */ made by .....
```

But I don't know how this is possible. If I echo $sidebar_table it returns **wp_w3care_sidebar_position**, so where is this wp_rainnews coming from? And what's with the quotes around it? If anyone can offer any help I would be very appreciative. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `wpdb::prepare` to inject table names - just use `"SELECT ... $sidebar_table"`